# How to count how many times a pair of specific values are repeated in an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two vectors of the same size, one for wave height and one for the period corresponding singly to the same point in time at which the measurement was taken. I want to know how many times the two specific data are repeated, for example:

Hs = [0.5 1.0 2.3 0.5 0.5]

Tm = [2.0 2.5 2.0 2.0 3.0]

So you can see:

Hs   Tm    Count

0.5  2.0     2

0.5  2.5     0

0.5  3.0     1

1.0  2.0     0

1.0  2.5     1...

I tried but the following errors occur, because I appear entire rows and columns without data and when I see my information for values​​.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import *

clf; cla; close
dat = loadtxt("ecmwf.dat", unpack=True)
HSf = dat[0,:]
HSf = around(HSf,decimals=1)
TMf = dat[1,:]
TMf = around(TMf,decimals=1)
mmat = zeros((31,141))

vhs = linspace(0.0,3.0,31)
vtm = linspace(0.0,14.0,141)

for i in xrange(0, vtm.size):
for k in xrange(0, vhs.size):
    if all((k <= vhs.size) & (i <= vtm.size)):
        lg1 = (TMf == vtm[i]) & (HSf == vhs[k])
        lg2 = sum(lg1)
    if lg2>=1:
        fg1 = text(i,k, str(lg2),horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',fontsize=6)
    mmat[k,i] = lg2
```

Comment: I think I had the first most complete answer, was what I provided what you were looking for, or did you want zero counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Counter` to count your pairs.

```
from collections import Counter

Hs = [0.5, 1.0, 2.3, 0.5, 0.5]
Tm = [2.0, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]

occurrences = Counter(zip(Hs, Tm))
for h in sorted(set(Hs)):
    for t in sorted(set(Tm)):
        print h, t, occurrences[(h,t)]
```

Result:

```
0.5 2.0 2
0.5 2.5 0
0.5 3.0 1
1.0 2.0 0
1.0 2.5 1
1.0 3.0 0
2.3 2.0 1
2.3 2.5 0
2.3 3.0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Counter` is available in the collections module for python 2.7 on:

```
import collections

Hs = [0.5, 1.0, 2.3, 0.5, 0.5]

Tm = [2.0, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]

pairs = zip(Hs, Tm)
```

we can zip the iterables together to neatly pair them up:

```
>>> print(list(pairs))
[(0.5, 2.0), (1.0, 2.5), (2.3, 2.0), (0.5, 2.0), (0.5, 3.0)]
```

So

```
pairs = zip(Hs, Tm)
counts = collections.Counter(pairs)

print(counts)
```

prints:

```
Counter({(0.5, 2.0): 2, (1.0, 2.5): 1, (0.5, 3.0): 1, (2.3, 2.0): 1})
```

And since Counter is merely a subclass of dict, we can treat it like a dict:

```
for pair, count in counts.items():
    print(pair, count)
```

prints out:

```
(1.0, 2.5) 1
(0.5, 3.0) 1
(0.5, 2.0) 2
(2.3, 2.0) 1
```

And if you want the counts of pairs that were not there, access the counter with the pair just like a key in a dict:

```
counts[(1.0, 3.0)]
```

returns

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `collections.Counter` for this task

```
import collections
import itertools

hs = 0.5, 1.0, 2.3, 0.5, 0.5
tn = 2.0, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0

pairCount = collections.Counter(itertools.izip(hs, tm))

print(pairCount)
```

Should result in something like:

```
Counter({(0.5, 2.0): 2, (1.0, 2.5): 1, (2.6, 2.0): 1, (0.5, 3.0): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

collections.Counter() will count the number of ocerrances in an iterable:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Hs = [0.5, 1.0, 2.3, 0.5, 0.5]
>>> Tm = [2.0, 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> repeats = Counter(zip(Hs,Tm))
>>> 
>>> aHs = np.array(Hs)
>>> aTm = np.array(Tm)
>>> aRepeats = Counter(zip(aHs,aTm))
>>> aRepeats
Counter({(0.5, 2.0): 2, (2.2999999999999998, 2.0): 1, (1.0, 2.5): 1, (0.5, 3.0): 1})
>>> 
>>> aRepeats[(0.5, 2.0)]
2
>>> repeats[(1.0, 2.5)]
1
>>>
```

Comment: So I was slow out of the starting block - not sure if I should delete this or not.